# VS regex search: Find Try..Finally with no Catch

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to use the Regular Expression search in Visual Studio to find all instances of a Try/Finally block without a Catch.

After reading the [help file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), I started with this which returns a match of **Try** without matching **End Try**.

```
~(End )Try\n
```

Then, I wanted to get a match where there was  **Finally**:

```
~(End )Try\n*Finally\n
```

This actually doesn't work.

The full, working Regex, I assume would look something like this:

```
~(End )(Sub|Function)*~(End )Try\n*~(Catch*\n)*Finally\n*End (Sub|Function)
```

That's try trying to say, within a Sub Or Function, return matches that have **Try/Finally** but no **Catch**.

Am I in the ballpark for accomplishing this search?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? The implementation of Regexes are radically different.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I have both VS2010 and VS2012; whichever is easier (assuming 2012)